# Error on `sudo systemctl restart nginx` while deploying on digital ocean droplet

Tags: nginx, github-actions, devops, cicd

I am trying to automate the deployment process on every push on main branch using Github Actions.

Here is my `workflow.yml`

```
name: Deploy to Production
on:
  push:
    branches: [pre-prod]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: uses node.js with version ${{ secrets.NODE_VERSION }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ secrets.NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          export DB_PROD_USERNAME=${{secrets.DB_PROD_USERNAME}}
          export DB_PROD_PASSWORD=${{secrets.DB_PROD_PASSWORD}}

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies and build frontend + backend app
        run: |
          npm install
          CI=false npm run build:client
          CI=false npm run build:server

      - name: Start server with PM2
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          npm install -g pm2
          pm2 start npm --name kanban-server -- run start --workspace=kanban-server

      - name: Configure Nginx
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install nginx
          sudo cp kanban.live.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/kanban.live
          sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/kanban.live /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

      - name: Restart Nginx
        run: |
          sudo systemctl restart nginx

      - name: Clean up
        run: |
          cd ../..
          rm -rf kanban-board
```

So the workflow is getting broken at `Restart Nginx` step. The error I am getting is kind of very vague and not very clear.

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Things I already tried:

1. I have even tried to remove the password prompt from the command, by doing this..

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myusername
```

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service nginx start,/usr/sbin/service nginx stop,/usr/sbin/service nginx restart
```

2. I also checked the port conflicts for the nginx, but it seems fine.

I don't know why is the error getting on restart command only.

Comment: Looks like your workflow is doing everything on the GHA runner itself and not the DO droplet. You should be SSHing into the DO droplet, copying your files there, and restart nginx there. See https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action.

Comment: Also, the step "**Set environment variables**" exporting secrets but each `run` is a different shell. Those variables won't be available to subsequent steps. See [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).